# add checkbox item inside Listbox gwt

Tags: java, gwt

How can we add Checkbox item inside Listbox or there is a checkboxlist i did not see ?

i want to get a list of checkboxes that  i will after  filter a list of appointments by checking those checkboxes

GWT  2.2 , java , eclipse

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't add widgets like a CheckBox to a ListBox, nor is there a CheckBoxList, but you can use a [CellList](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.2/com/google/gwt/user/cellview/client/CellList.html) with a CompositeCell (TextCell + CheckboxCell) and it'll do what you want.

Comment: can you share the code or example where you had implemented check box + label in listbox item

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can add checkboxes within the Listboxe.
You can probably create a List box with multiple selection enabled.

```
ListBox list = new ListBox();

list.setVisibleItemCount(10);
list.setMultipleSelect(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is something using GXT's XTemplate (if you want only GWT then use Template).
Other than that, how you pass your data is something you can define, but if you go with GXTs ModelData then this could work.

https://gist.github.com/Aadi1/4949994