# How To Add Checkbox in Selection Cell GWT

Tags: java, gwt

In Gwt DataGrid we have SelectionCell in Column ,in which we can pass List.
I want a selection Cell with Checkboxes and Text in it.So that on dropdown we will get checkbox and String text list.
Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to build this cell yourself. Follow the tutorial:

[GWT Custom Cells](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideUiCustomCells.html)

Comment: I want code for that, i have tried but not able to do it.

Comment: Then you should share your code and ask a specific question.

Answer (score 0):

According to [java documentation](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/cell/client/SelectionCell.html) you can pass to SelectionCell constructor only List of Strings, so I am not sure there is a way to do it like this.

However, there was a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5351854/add-checkbox-item-inside-listbox-gwt) about how to add checkbox to a listbox, check it, it can help. Guys advises to use use a CellList with a CompositeCell (TextCell + CheckboxCell).

Plus GWT has quite good [library of samples](http://samples.gwtproject.org/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCellSampler), try to follow them.